# debian mysql error running shared postrotate script for /var/log/mysql.log

Tags: mysql, debian

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:

> error: error running shared postrotate script for /var/log/mysql.log
>   /var/log/mysql/mysql.log

/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

> run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1

Answer (score 12):

The shared postrotate script tries to access the mysql database but fails to do so, probably because the password doesn't match.

In Debian, mysql is controlled via the mysql user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'. The password for this user is stored in **/etc/mysql/debian.cnf**.

```
cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

Note the password being used in this file. If you have a password for root (like you should), you will need to get into mysql with the following command.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Otherwise, you can just type 'mysql'.  In the **mysql>** prompt, run the following.

```
GRANT RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, LOCK TABLES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

Substitute the password found in **/etc/mysql/debian.cnf** in place of the Xs. And finally...

```
quit
```

You should now be able to restart your mysql server with no errors using the command:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

However, the restart is not required.

Comment: Thanks me, this information is available on the internet, but the most popular post says to put the phrase IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD in the mysql command instead of just IDENTIFIED BY.

Comment: Your welcome other me.  The crazy thing is that when you do use IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'testpass', mysql will actually set the user's password to 'testpass' in plain text! Making the actual password readable to anyone who has read access to the 'mysql' table.  This is clearly not good.  So thank you for posting this question, it needed to be cleared up.

Comment: what is this I don't even..

Comment: I have Ubuntu 15.10 and the /etc/mysql/debian.cnf file shows user `root`  and password is empty. I mean there's no `debian-sys-maint` user.
What would be the solution here?

Comment: For me , the password field was blank in debian.cnf (Debian 10 , MariaDB 10.6.4)

Comment: Thanks, the grant worked for me **after** I a) created the user, which didn't exist `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password_from_debian_cnf>';` and b) used the `GRANT` query above **without** `IDENTIFIED BY '<password_from_debian_cnf>'` Still need to see if `logrotate` doesn't fail on the `postrotate`

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 18 my fix was this:

```sh
mysql -u root -p <<_EOF_
ALTER USER 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '`sudo grep --only-matching  --max-count=1 --perl-regexp 'password\s*=\s*\K.*' /etc/mysql/debian.cnf | sed --expression='s/'\''/\\'\''/g'`';
_EOF_
```

This extracts the password from `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` making sure to escape any single quotes it might contain:

```sh
    sudo grep                           \
        --only-matching                 \
        --max-count=1                   \
        --perl-regexp                   \
        'password\s*=\s*\K.*'           \
        /etc/mysql/debian.cnf           \
|   sed                                 \
      --expression='s/'\''/\\'\''/g'`
```

and inserts it in this bit of SQL:

```
ALTER USER 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<extracted-and-escaped-pw-inserted-here>';
```

... which is then fed directly to the standard input of the `mysql -u root -p` client.

Answer (score 0):

For Debian 9 (Stretch): the `debian-sys-maint` user is gone, so the solution is to get rid of the `debian.cnf` in either:

- `/etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server` (for MariaDB or MySQL)
- `/etc/logrotate.d/percona-xtradb-cluster-5.7` (for Percona XtraDB Cluster)

In this file you'll find:

```
            MYADMIN="/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf"
```

which should be changed to:

```
            MYADMIN="/usr/bin/mysqladmin"
```

I had to change it with Percona XtraDB Cluster, which for the time being isn't released for Debian Stretch, hence the logrotate script is currently wrong.